# rails routes problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

here are my routes.i want to prevent duplicate url

```
match ':id' => 'people#show'
match 'people/:id' => redirect("%{id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
match '(people)/:id' => 'people#show'
```

[Bound Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters)

Comment: `/people/:id(.:format)      {:to=>#<Proc:0xa09b500@/home/rails_noob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:366 (lambda)>}`